# Basic guessing game not functioning the way I want it to

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this game to run ad infinitum until the user enters "q" or "quit". For some reason, this isn't quite working out with what I have. I initially tried to do this with two functions but failed miserably, so I consolidated for right now into one function to try to get it going. Still failing, but not as bad.

```
#Ex9: Guessing game. Generate a number between 1-9 and provide info whether its too high or low

import random 
#print("Type q or quit to quit") 
#guess = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 to 9: ")) 

def guessing_function():  
    while True: 
        quit1 = print("Type q or quit to quit")
        guess = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 to 9: ")) 
        value = random.randint(1,9)
        if quit1 == "quit".lower() or "q".lower():
            print("Ok we will stop") 
            break 
        elif guess > value: 
            print(f"The computer generated {value}") 
            print(f"You picked {guess}. That value is too high")
        elif guess < value: 
            print(f"The computer generated {value}")
            print(f"You picked {guess}. That value is too low")
        elif guess == value:
            print(f"The computer generated {value}")
            print(f"You picked {guess}. That value is correct!")

          


guessing_function()
```

Basically the issue is that the script just stops after one loop, rather than continue on without the user's input.... Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your if statement is checking for `if quit1 == "quit".lower() or "q".lower():` first part but the second part is always be True.

Comment: There are at least three issues here: the linked duplicate, a typo (you call `print` in one place where you clearly intended to call `input`), and a logical issue (if you want to stop immediately when `quit` is typed, then you should check whether `quit` was typed *before* prompting for a number).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to check if the user wanted to quit.

checking `"quit".lower()` is not correct. `"quit"` is already lower.

Also the `or` part of the if statement is incorrect. It will always be True.

Instead you want to check if lowercase of `quit1` is either `"quit"` or `"q"`.

You can do that by giving `if quit1.lower() in ("quit","q")`. By using `in ("quit","q")`, the if statement checks against the items in the tuple. This is a much better way to check when you have multiple values to check.

```
def guessing_function():  
    while True: 
        quit1 = print("Type q or quit to quit")
        guess = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 to 9: ")) 
        value = random.randint(1,9)

        if quit1.lower() in ("quit","q"): #fixed this line

            print("Ok we will stop") 
            break 
        elif guess > value: 
            print(f"The computer generated {value}") 
            print(f"You picked {guess}. That value is too high")
        elif guess < value: 
            print(f"The computer generated {value}")
            print(f"You picked {guess}. That value is too low")
        elif guess == value:
            print(f"The computer generated {value}")
            print(f"You picked {guess}. That value is correct!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` doesn't prompt for user input(and returns None always), you should replace it with `input` instead.

The `if` is also wrong, it should be `if quit1 == "quit" or quit1 == "q":`. [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) explains it better than I could.

Comment: Ah I missed this simple fix, but it didn't solve the problem. The thing still just goes into the first "If" and stops running. Thank you

Comment: why would you give `"quit".lower()` when `quit` is already lower?

Comment: @JoeFerndz fixed